# No Login with LDAP on MediaWIki

Tags: centos, php, active-directory, ldap

I've been reading a lot about how to connect my wikimedia with ldap, and authenticate users with that plugin and users of a specific group. I still don't achieve anything, it always tells me that the password is wrong.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication/AD_Configuration_Examples

what could be wrong?

```html
require_once ('extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php');
require_once ('includes/auth/AuthManager.php');
$wgAuth = new LdapAuthenticationPlugin();
$wgLDAPDomainNames = array('transporte.com');
$wgLDAPServerNames = array('transporte.com' => 'MTNWMC300.transporte.com');
$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array( "transporte.com" => "clear" );
$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array( "transporte.com" => "sAMAccountName" );
$wgLDAPProxyAgent =  array('transporte.com' => 'CN=svc_mediawiki,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=transporte,DC=com');
$wgLDAPProxyAgentPassword = array('transporte.com' => 'Vzla*021-');
$wgLDAPBaseDNs = array('transporte.com' => 'DC=transporte,DC=com');
$wgLDAPGroupBaseDNs = array('transporte.com' => 'OU=Users,OU=IMSO,OU=IT-ADM,DC=transporte,DC=com',);
$wgLDAPUserBaseDNs = array('transporte.com' => 'OU=Users,OU=IMSO,OU=IT-ADM,DC=transporte,DC=com',);
$wgLDAPRetrievePrefs = array( "transporte.com" => "true" );
$wgLDAPPreferences = array('transporte.com' => array( 'email' => 'mail','realname' => 'displayname'));
$wgLDAPPort = array('transporte.com' => 389,);
$wgLDAPUseLocal = false;
$wgMinimalPasswordLength = 1;
```

I checked the connection with this php and launched connection success, so I could not say what the problem is:

```html
// variables de conexion ldap
    $ldapuser  = 'CN=s-mediawiki,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=transporte,DC=com'; 
    $ldappassword = 'Vzla*021-';
// coneccion al ldap server
    $ldapconexx = ldap_connect("transporte.com")
    or die("No connection to LDAP.");
        if ($ldapconexx) {
// prueba de conexion al ldap server
                $ldapconex = ldap_bind($ldapconexx, $ldapuser, $ldappassword);
// prueba de conexion de usuario
                if ($ldapconex) {
                    echo "LDAP bind success...";
                } else {
                    echo "LDAP bind failed..dd.";
                }
        }
```

Thanks!

PD: sorry my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You have different passwords in your two examples. (And different service accounts.) If your connection testing isn't using the same credentials as the code you are trying to debug, it's going to make things difficult to troubleshoot. Can you confirm that the credentials used in your config file are correct?

Comment: password is good, i change for StackExchange public :) , Thanks